# How to hide an HTML element if a value is present in an array

Tags: angular, observable, angularfire2

My controller retrieves an Observable (a FirebaseObjectObservable actually) that I consume in my view with the async pipe.

My object as a list of id called 'joiners'.

I would like to hide a 'join' button whenever the current user id 'cuid' is present in the 'joiners' array.

I tried something like this:

```
[hidden]="(event$ | async)?.joiners.indexOf(cuid) > -1"
```

But it is not working... any idea?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

for your button try

```
<button *ngIf="joiners.indexOf(cuid) >= 0">BUTTON</button>
```

Comment: Even if cuid is a variable of my controller?

Comment: Oups... actually that was my mistake, it works perfectly as I wrote it in the first place. My mistake was that joiners wasn't an array but an object.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, this is perfectly working as long as 'joiners' is an array.